# Real eigensolutions to the diffusion equation.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, boundary-value-problem

How can I find the real eigensolutions to the diﬀusion equation

$u_t$ = $\left(x^2 u_x\right)_x,$

modeling diffusion in an inhomogeneous medium on the half-line $x>0?$

And which solutions satisfy the Dirichlet boundary conditions $u(t,1)=u(t,2)=0?$

Comment: Do you have an initial condition? Something like $u(0,x)=?$

Comment: No, there are no initial conditions for this question.

Comment: Well, you could use the Laplace Transform in the time domain, which would give you an ODE in $x$, treating $s$ like a constant. I get $sU-u(0,x)=2xU'+x^2U''. $ This is actually a Cauchy-Euler equation in $x$. You might get a decent inverse transform expression out of it. [EDIT] Never mind, you don't. You'd probably have to do the complex line integral.

Comment: Is there not a simpler way to solve this equation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can separate the variables. Suppose $u(t,x)=X(x) T(t),$ and use $\dot{T}=\dfrac{dT}{dt}$ and $X'=\dfrac{dX}{dx}$ for temporal and spatial derivatives, respectively. Then we have
\begin{align*}
u_t&=2xu_x+x^2u_{xx}\\
X\dot{T}&=2xX'T+x^2X''T \quad\text{divide by } XT:\\
\frac{\dot{T}}{T}&=\frac{2xX'}{X}+\frac{x^2X''}{X}=k\\
\dot{T}&=kT\\
2xX'+x^2X''&=kX.
\end{align*}
These are both fairly easily solvable. We obtain
\begin{align*}
T&=Ae^{kt}\\
X&=x^{-\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{2} \sqrt{4 k+1}}
    \left(c_1+c_2 x^{\sqrt{4 k+1}}\right)\\
U(t,x)&=Ae^{kt}x^{-\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{2} \sqrt{4 k+1}}
    \left(c_1+c_2 x^{\sqrt{4 k+1}}\right).
\end{align*}
Imposing the boundary conditions, I'm afraid, yields only the trivial solution $X=0.$ So what I have shown is that, of all separable solutions (which might be the only solutions, given that the PDE is linear - you might be able to prove existence and uniqueness of solutions), only the trivial solution works for your boundary conditions.